# threading in Filewatcher window service

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have written a window service that uses Filewatcher to monitor the creation of file in a particular folder.however,my question is in real environment,many files (approx 20-30) comes in the folder in production environment.How should I handle such huge data files.Do i need to implememt threading or something.for threading,any sample code will be appreciated as i am not sure how to do.
Code is below:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{        
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("C:\\Users\\\\Data.xml");

    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        strDir = xn["Directory"].InnerText;
        fileMask = xn["FileMask"].InnerText;
        strBatfile = xn["Batch"].InnerText;
        strlog = xn["Log"].InnerText; 
    }

    m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();


    m_Watcher.Filter = fileMask;
    m_Watcher.Path = strDir+ "\\";
    m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                     | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;


    m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);

    m_Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleated);
    m_Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);


    m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   
}
```

Handler code is below:

```
private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Log.getLogger("File Created- Filename :" + e.Name + " at timestamp : " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), strlog);
    string strFileExt = e.Name;

    var extension = Path.GetExtension(strFileExt).ToUpper();
    try
    {
        if (extension == ".txt")
        {
            string MyBatchFile = strBatfile;
            string parameterFilename = strFileExt;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MyBatchFile);

            Log.getLogger("File Processed after executing batch:  Filename ->:" + e.Name + " " + "Batch File Executed- > " + strBatfile + " at timestamp : " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), strlog);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        CustomException.Write(CustomException.CreateExceptionString(exception, strFileExt));
    }
    finally
    {
        m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Question2-

> What are the best practice to write in Onstop() method.

Comment: What do you meant by how to handle? you're not showing any of your event handlers. So, we have no idea what you do there and thus unanswerable.

Comment: Appolozies.i added the handler code also.Basically looking for ".txt" files and executing a batch file every time ".txt" comes in folder via ftp.

Comment: Ok, what is the problem with this code? It seems you're not doing any time consuming work in your handler. So I don't think any worker thread is needed. This code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks,the only issue,i was thinking ....since almost 40-50 ".txt" comes in the folder,also the bacth file does a bit comples task that can take some time.Will it affect Filewatcher or some threading should be done to handle that???Any design error in this.

Comment: 40-50 are very small. No need to worry about it. Only thing to worry about is: make sure those process created by `Process.Start(MyBatchFile)` terminates soon, otherwise your code will create many processes which will put pressure for the operating system with too many processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround so thought to post it.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

         current_directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
              string Xml_Path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
             xml.Load(current_directory+"\\Data.xml");//suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"


                XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
                 foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                 {
                     strDir = xn["Directory"].InnerText;
                     fileMask = xn["FileMask"].InnerText;
                     strBatfile = xn["Batch"].InnerText;
                     strlog = xn["Log"].InnerText;


                 }

            m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();


            m_Watcher.Filter = fileMask;
            m_Watcher.Path = strDir + "\\";
            m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;




            m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);

            m_Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleated);
            m_Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);


            m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            CustomException.Write(CustomException.CreateExceptionString(exception.ToString()));
        }

    }
```